# Programmatically trigger online-only Dropbox file download on macOS

Tags: macos, dropbox

I often write console-based apps and scripts, on macOS especially. They unable to access the zero-length contents of "online-only" Dropbox placeholder files and I have manually sync local copies through the UI.

Is there a Mac file API - or even a console command that runs in the background - I can programmatically access that will trigger or force an online-only Dropbox file to download a local copy?

I've tried console commands such as `cat`, C API's such as `fopen()`, and Mac/Cocoa API's such as `NSFileManager`, `NSFileHandle`, and `[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile]`, without success. The placeholder files remain at zero bytes.

Comment: There's a Python SDK https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python so it would probably be fairly simple to pull down any zero-length files, though I can't imagine why `cat` or `wc` wouldn't work if Dropbox is installed and running correctly. Do files you place in Dropbox get uploaded to the online site properly?

Comment: @MarkSetchell yes, everything works correctly otherwise. I tried `cat` and (just now) `wc` and neither downloads the file. Are you able to get those to work successfully on a Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Dropbox doesn't offer an interface for programmatically managing this setting, such as to set a file to "offline", but I'll pass this along as a feature request. I can't promise if or when that might be implemented though.

[Online-only files should be automatically downloaded when opened](https://help.dropbox.com/sync/make-files-online-only) though, except for [some issues that may affect users on macOS](https://help.dropbox.com/sync/online-only-mac). That's not part of the API itself though, so if that's not working as expected for you, you may want to [contact support](https://www.dropbox.com/support/).

Alternatively, as Mark noted in the comments, you can use [the Dropbox API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers) instead, to download file data directly. For example, you can use [the /2/files/download endpoint](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-download), or [the corresponding `files_download` method](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dropbox.html#dropbox.dropbox_client.Dropbox.files_download) in [the official Dropbox Python SDK](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python).

Comment: RE: "automatically downloaded when opened" - this only applies to files opened through the standard Finder and file selection dialogs, correct? That does work correctly in that case, but if I use "mvim <path/to/online-only/file.txt>", or any other console-based program, then it does not download automatically.

Comment: That would be a very weird implementation if only opening via Finder works but not via command-line! Maybe try `open -e YOURFILE` from the command-line which will open it in TextEdit but the Finder will be involved. Or try `open -a NeoVim YOURFILE` which will use NeoVim but also involve Finder. I'm intrigued to hear your results!

Comment: @MarkSetchell yes, using `open` works, albeit with the unwanted side effect of opening TextEdit or an associated app. There's the `-j` option to hide the app but it doesn't seem to change anything. My goal is to be to be able to trigger a download of any type of file without having additional Mac apps popping up. Given that using Finder, open file dialogs, and `open` do trigger a download, it seems like there must be some kind of Mac file API (or AppleScript even?) that would similarly trigger a download without actually opening associated apps.

Comment: How are you causing files to become *"non-resident"* on your local disk for test purposes?

Comment: Is this in any kind of official issue tracker? It would be great to have a link to it so we can vote it up.

Comment: @MarkSetchell you can force a file to become non-resident by doing something as crazy as editing it from python. When I'm writing to a file from a python process (fairly frequently), and opening it again, I get intermittent issues like this sometimes.